# Append headers to the upload function in ng2-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload, ng2-file-upload

I am using ng2-file-upload in angular2 and have an input field for file and submit button like this :

```
 <input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" (click)="item.upload()" [disabled]="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess"> 
    Upload
 </button>
```

where item is in uploader.queue

In my TS file I have declared uploader like this :

```
public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader(
    {
      url: URL
    }
  );
```

**This seems to work perfectly fine.**

But now, I have the requirement to append few headers to this upload function. 
So, I tried this :

```
public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader(
    {
      url: URL,
      headers: [{ name: 'foo', value: 'extraHeader'}]
    }
  );
```

which adds foo to my headers but all the other headers like content type:multipart/formdata with boundary are removed and the upload function no longer is able to upload the file. 
**How can I keep the existing headers added by upload function by default and also be able to add my extra header 'foo'**

Comment: maybe this? https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/905

Comment: @vegazz : I am not able to add it to the header. I dont want additional data in body.

Comment: how about appending the header with your values? may be concat your header with the default one?

Comment: @DeepakJha : Yes I want to exactly do that.But I am not able to. can you post a working example if you have.

Comment: well may be like this headers.concat([{ name: 'foo', value: 'extraHeader'}]), m not sure if this will work but give this a go and let me know if that works. We can try other way as well.

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal any luck?

Comment: @DeepakJha : It doesnt work like that. Uploader in ng2-file-upload doesnt give you the options to add headers like that.Please check the module first.

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal just seen the document, I wonder if you could write or append headers using the interceptor instead. In my applications I use interceptors to attach custom headers, if your approach hasnt worked as yet try doing it using the interceptor. If need help in writing interceptor let me know I can send some codes to do so . ....